# MapReduce: Join data files and summarize information

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I have the following data sets:

Data set #1 that provides shows and the number of viewers of that show:

```
TVShow1,25
TVShow2,30
TVShow3,7
TVShow1,15
```

Data set #2 that provides channels that broadcast each show:

```
TVShow4,BBC
TVShow2,COM
TVShow1,TNT
TVShow3,TNT
```

I want to calculated the total number of viewers of each show on the channel TNT, e.g.

```
TVShow1 40
TVShow3 7
```

I have the following mapper:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    line       = line.strip()
    key_value  = line.split(",")
    key_in     = key_value[0]
    value_in   = key_value[1]

    if (value_in == 'TNT' or value_in.isdigit()):
        print( '%s\t%s' % (key_in, value_in) )
```

And the following reducer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

prev_TV_show = "  "
line_cnt           = 0 
tnt_found = False
curr_TV_show_total_cnt = 0

for line in sys.stdin:
    line       = line.strip() 
    key_value  = line.split('\t')
    line_cnt   = line_cnt+1     

    curr_TV_show  = key_value[0]
    value_in   = key_value[1]

    if curr_TV_show != prev_TV_show:
        prev_TV_show = curr_TV_show     

        if (line_cnt>1 and tnt_found == True): 
            print('{0} {1}'.format(curr_TV_show,curr_TV_show_total_cnt))
            tnt_found = False
            curr_TV_show_total_cnt = 0


    if (value_in == 'TNT'): 
        tnt_found = True 
    else:
        curr_TV_show_total_cnt += int(value_in)
```

Then I tested the code as follows:

```
cat data_file*.txt | ./my_mapper.py | sort | ./my_reducer.py
```

However, it seams that total number of viewers of the first line is incorrect. It looks like it is merged between two TV shows. Is there any error in the code related to managing the first line?

Comment: @Ben Watson: Sorry, the error was just due to the lack of memory. Now it works. However, anyway the result is incorrect. So, I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Could you provide some sample incorrect output in your question please? Just so I can be sure of what you're seeing.

Comment: @Ben Watson: I see the first line as TVShow3 47. The rest of lines seem to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

I think that there are 2 problems in your code -

1. Updating prev_TV_show causes you to print the wrong value. You
   actually want to print the prev_TV_show with its' count, not the
   curr_TV_show
2. Printing the last iteration value - you need to add an additional print (+condition) outside the loop

Comment: Thank you! Now it works. Just one doubt. Do you know why the output of testing (cat data_file*.txt | ./my_mapper.py | sort | ./my_reducer.py) is slightly different from the result returned by running the Hadoop streaming command? In particular, TVShow5 is equal to 10 after testing, while it is equal to 0 after running the streaming command. It's a bit strange.